# Search string for specific value=

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to search for a specific value within an html response using the requests library

```
import requests

while True:

 url = 'https://www.example.com/'

 page = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, verify=False)

 var = page.content
```

The value would appear to be like a dictionary, but I cannot convert the whole response.content to a dict using : var = dict(page.content) as it gives error "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

I have attempted to use the re.search method such as this :

```
  searchObj = re.search( r'(.*)id="X" value=(.*?) .*', var, re.M)
 if searchObj:
  print "search --> searchObj.group() : ", searchObj.group()
```

but it is not what I am looking for - the end goal is to find a specific value within the content returned from a website request, it would look something like this in the content : `<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="test" id="test" value="12345" />` - with the data needing to be extracted as value="12345" or more specifically just the 12345

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use beautifulsoup, find the tag and extract the attribute

Comment: I really really hope you either own this site or have spoken with the owner, because if you don't know what you doing and you're hitting that page with an infinite loop, someone is going to be very justifiably angry with you.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist while you are right that he shouldn't scrape a page with an infinite loop without a timeout, it really won't matter. Most modern sites are built with either Apache or Nginx, and they will close his connection if too many connection attempts are made within a short period of time.

Comment: @nivixzixer And I run an anti-virus but I'm still going to be justifiably angry if you try to infect my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is preferable to parse XML and HTML using a specialised library but if it is a one-off operation and the output is predictable, it is fine to use a regex. The following re should work.

```
r'id=\"test\"\svalue=\"(.*?)\"'
```

The `(.*)` in the beginning is capturing everything.

Comment: searchObj = re.search( r'id=\"X\"\svalue=\"(.*?)\"', var, re.M|re.I)

if searchObj:
   print searchObj.group(1)
else:
   print "Nothing found!!"

Using your comment I was able to start extracting only what I need from responses - appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex for this, use a library that was made for that, for example [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
element = soup.find(attrs={'id': 'hplogo'}) # will search for the 'google' logo
print element

>> <div align="left" id="hplogo" onload="window.lol&amp;&amp;lol()" style="height:110px;width:276px;background:url(/images/srpr/logo9w.png) no-repeat" title="Google"><div nowrap="" style="color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;position:relative;top:70px;left:218px">׳™׳©׳¨׳�׳�</div></div>
```

Comment: One of my favorite posts on the site!

Comment: This works to print the whole element - but I am looking only for the 1 value="" etc - works great to print only that subsection that I was looking to dissect but I need to refine it further. Ty so far

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
import re
import requests

VALUE_RGX = re.compile(r'id="X" value="([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)"')

url = 'https://www.example.com/'
page = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, verify=False)

matched_groups = VALUE_RGX.match(page.text)
if len(matched_groups) > 1:
    print("Found Value: {}".format(matched_groups[1]))
else:
    print("Did not find value..")
```

Comment: error "if len(matched_groups > 0): TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Comment: Oops, had a typo. Should be `len(matched_groups) > 1`. I'll update the post